# window.location=... does and doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, debugging, navigation

I have a JS function to go to the next page when clicking a button. This works for step 1 but not for step 2.

When executing the function below with `nextstep = 'form', _bookingCode = 123` the lower log shows `goto booking_form.php?fromDate=2022-07-20` and the page loads exactly that page.

Now with `nextstep = 'details', _bookingCode = 123`, I see `goto booking_details.php?bookingCode=123` but the page loaded is `/mbooking_form.php?`

I have copied code and file name `booking_details.php`above one another: match

`console.log(window.location.pathname);` provides `/mbooking_form.php` which is in the same directory as  `booking_details.php` (and I also tried `file = "../booking_details.php";`...)

I removed basically all content from `booking_details.php` including `$_GET` to prevent page problems.

But it keeps loading `http://localhost:8888/mbooking_form.php?`

What could be the problem or what else can I do to trace the cause?

```js
function goToNextBookingPage(nextStep, _bookingCode) {
    lan = document.getElementById('lan').value;
    switch (nextStep) {
        case "form":
            total = document.getElementById('total').value;
            total = total.substr(0, total.length-2);
            file = "../mbooking_form.php";
            arguments = '?fromDate=' + selectedDate[0] 
            break;
        case "details": 
            phone = document.getElementById("inputPhone").value;
            notes = document.getElementById("inputNotes").value;
console.log(window.location.pathname);          
            file = "mbooking_details.php";
            arguments = '?bookingCode=' + bookingCode 
            break;
    }
    urlStr = file + arguments;
console.log("goto " + urlStr);
    window.location = urlStr;
}
```

Comment: [See here for more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) window.location alternates

Answer (score 0):

**arguments** is a reserve keyword in JavaScript. This may creating issue in your expected result. And best to use back-tick(Javacsript template literal) instead of concatenating. 
And also in your **case : "form"** the way you added the URL using dot dot(..) it will not work in that way. you have to provide exact URL to redirect in expected location. Please see the comment in the code. 
Try the below code.

```
function goToNextBookingPage(nextStep, _bookingCode) {
    lan = document.getElementById('lan').value;
    switch (nextStep) {
        case "form":
            total = document.getElementById('total').value;
            total = total.substr(0, total.length-2);
            file = `../mbooking_form.php?fromDate=${selectedDate[0]}`; // provide the exact URL location instead of dot dot(..)
            break;
        case "details": 
            phone = document.getElementById("inputPhone").value;
            notes = document.getElementById("inputNotes").value;
            console.log(window.location.pathname);          
            file = `mbooking_details.php?bookingCode=${_bookingCode}`;
            break;
    }
    urlStr = file;
    console.log("goto " + urlStr);
    window.location = urlStr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Amin. However, `file = '../mbooking_form.php'` works fine, it is `mbooking_details.php`that doesn't. `urlStr = file + arguments;` also provides the expected result

Comment: Then please re-check **mbooking_details.php** file location  and naming is okay.